Is the use of optoisolators to isolate and clean a signal before an OR gate input good practice? If not what is better?
I am designing an alarm system for my employer. I am planning to use an OR gate to connect three different switches and have it so if any one of them are flipped the alarm will go off.
The problem I have ran into is that the environment is electrically noisy (welders, air compressors, high voltage AC, etc). When I used my analog discovery three to look at the noise along one 200ft wire there was a 1V sign wave and each time a welder started up really high frequency noise of a couple tenths of a volt.
My current idea/solution is to use opto-isolation to keep the logic circuit completely on the PCB. I included a low pass filter to taper down the noise at the input of the opto-isolators.
My question is if all this is a good idea? I haven't really been able to turn much up on the internet and I am not all that experience in this.
Here is the schematic in question:

Edited the Title of the question to say what may be a better method just to make it make more sense for accepting an answer.

If you’re creating an alarm system for an industrial customer, you should look into a concept called Fully Supervised Loop. FSL systems use switch and end-of-line terminators to detect whether a loop is in normal, alarm or tamper. It only requires two wires, and multiple alarms can be connected to the same loop.
More here: https://technolysis-hts.gr/knowledge-base/designing-a-fully-supervised-loop-fsl-eol-alarm-system/
You can use shielded twisted pair cable to reduce common-mode interference, and feed the pair through a common mode filter.
Could you use an optoisolator for FSL? Maybe, if you are mindful of its Current Transfer Ratio, or CTR. You can then use it measure loop current.
Here's an idea to make an FSL with an optoisolator that covers 3 zones (simulate it here):

Basically, this measures current and feeds it to a window comparator to sense the loop state:

Loop Normal (2.2k): all switches closed, the opto output will be above 4V.
Loop Alarm (6.9k to 16.3k): one or more of the switches opens, the opto out will be 1.1 ~ 3.3V
Tamper: (open circuit), the output will be zero.

The comparators decode this voltage to drive status.
The transformer-y thing on the loop is a common-mode filter. You can just run your wire through a ferrite bead and do the same thing.

I really like this circuit and think I at least roughly understand how it works except for the  purpose of the transformer and how that section works. Could you give me some clarification on that.

Also this is for an industrial 'customer' (I'm just a regular employee there) and my task is just to create a alarm system one step up from what we currently have. My regular job is not circuit design but I have been moving into that more recently. The reason I thought about using an optocoupler is two fold.

I was thinking about how current signals are harder to be disrupted by noise and thought maybe I could use that to my advantage.
I have used them before so I am familiar with them.


The ‘transformer’ is a common-mode filter. It rejects noise that appears on both wires, such as coupling from motors, while passing the current loop.

That makes sense. I have one more question.
I am try to model noise into the simulator, but am not sure how. I am adding a noise generator input with a resistor. If you want to see it is here simulation

Couple your noise source to the loop using capacitors.

The point of an opto-isolator is to allow isolation, and it's not connected in a way that isolates.
Both the input and output side of the isolator use the same ground and same 5V.
It might be useless and expensive to put an opto-isolator in a circuit when none of it's properties are not really used. Sort of like Arduino relay modules that boast having this mythical optoisolator between GPIO pin and the relay driving transistor in a same way.

Yah. I do tend to use opto-couplers for the wrong reason (bad habits). In this case I had the idea that opto-couplers might work ok because it would change my pure voltage input into a current signal which may be harder to disrupt. I was also concerned about potential voltage spikes coming from the long wires and damaging the gate pins

A resistor will sort of do that. Filter and protection components remove noise and spikes. A transistor or relay could do that as well.

Many alternative methods will reduce crosstalk to Common and differential mode noise.

Impedance control with filters and attenuation of stray C noise may be defined.
STP cable can be used to create constant current loops or RJ45 jacks with Baluns and terminating resistors  that offer good immunity and even better with shielding.
The Optoisolator offers excellent high voltage isolation with isolated supplies for CMRR, the cable wire matching can degrade AC CMRR but DC will be filtered so that spikes do not trigger a false alarm.
A coded protocol would make communication more difficult to create an alarm code with noise. Like sending continuous frequencies for each source and using a touchtone decoder to identify the source and amplitude modulation to indicate an alarm with logic for each signal.
Identify every possible fault and come up with a method to detect a fault, the source from a true alarm and define the threshold to failure.
Before you do any design investigate the best practices of commercial alarm systems and compare costs, performance, fault detection and correction methods and compare with your results. Then write a design spec and budget.

